# Loading Admin Toolbar in header not Footer to Scroll it with page

Tags: admin-bar

I'm trying to load the admin toolbar on the front end immediately after the `head` tag in my header.

I'm trying to achieve something like this as opposed to how it usually gets loaded at the end of the page.

```
<header>
<div id="wpadminbar" class="show-wp-toolbar" role="navigation">...</div>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

I want the menu bar to flow naturally with the rest of the page instead of being fixed so when I scroll up it hides with everything else.

I've found the admin bar gets loaded in "wordpress/wp-settings.php" on line 146:

```
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/admin-bar.php' );
```

And admin bar itself is at:

```
   wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php 
   wordpress/wp-includes/admin-bar.php
```

However, I'm new at PHP and have had trouble figuring out how the order of page elements is determined.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a CSS edit. You don't need to alter how or where the admin menu loads. Add ...

```
#wpadminbar {
  position: absolute;
}
```

to your theme's stylesheet.